# SVG animateMotion & JavaScript

Tags: jquery, animation, svg

I use path and animateMotion. It works well until I try to generate it dynamically using JavaScipt. I use [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html)

I tried to append animation code usind native method:

```
    $("#scheme_wrapper").svg();
    var svg=box.svg('get');
    svg.add('<rect x="10" y="10" width="20" height="20" fill="red"><animateMotion id="KKK" path="M300,200 a100,100 0 1,0 -100,100 a100,100 0 0,0 100,-100" dur="20s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite" /></rect>');
```

I see small red rectangle but animation doesn't start. But if i create svg file with this animation code - rectagle successfully moves. Why? How to create dynamically animateMotion using JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution:

```
var svg=box.svg('get');
svg.rect(0,0,80,50,{fill:"red",id:"rectObj"});
var motion=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","animateMotion");
motion.setAttribute("dur", "20s");
motion.setAttribute("repeatCount", "indefinite");
motion.setAttribute("path", "M300,200 a100,100 0 1,0 -100,100 a100,100 0 0,0 100,-100");
document.getElementById("rectObj").appendChild(motion);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using Safari or Chrome right? I'm afraid [dynamically added animation](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82647) doesn't work there. Try Firefox or Opera instead.

Comment: I use Firefox and Opera. Every browser has such problem

Comment: Check out the testcase in the bugzilla link in my answer. That works in Firefox and Opera.